# Trivial parsec example produces a type error

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to get this trivial parsec code to compile

```
import Text.Parsec
simple = letter
```

but I keep getting this error

```
No instance for (Stream s0 m0 Char)
  arising from a use of `letter'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Stream s0 m0 Char)
In the expression: letter
In an equation for `simple': simple = letter
```

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. Yes, they concern the same basic issue, but that question is general, where this one is specific. Somebody searching for this specific instance of the problem doesn't need to know the full details of what the restriction is, they just need specific recommendations of how to resolve the problem - particularly, they need to know what the correct type signature for such a function would be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you have ran against the *monomorphism restriction*. This restriction means: If a variable is declared with no explicit arguments, its type has to be monomorphic. This forces the typechecker to pick a particular instance of `Stream`, but it can't decide.

There are two ways to fight it:

1. Give `simple` an explicit signature:

   ```
   simple :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Char
   simple = letter
   ```
2. Disable the monorphism restriction:

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
   import Text.Parsec
   simple = letter
   ```

See [What is the monomorphism restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction) for more information on the monomorphism restriction.

Comment: Oh, normally you get an error saying "you can't do this due to the monomorphism restriction" when this happens.

Comment: I don't know why this is like it is. It ay be related to the new type inference engine in GHC 7.