# Type errors with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using Parsec 3.1.2 with GHC 7.4.1 to try to write a parser for a somewhat hairy data file format. I've what I'd think is a pretty trivial case, but I'm getting a type error. I'm trying to follow the applicative functor examples from Real World Haskell.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (many, optional, (<|>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String
import Control.Applicative
p_int = many char ' ' *> many1 digit <* many char ' '
```

Now, originally I got the following type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]'
            with actual type `Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 [a0]'
In the return type of a call of `many1'
In the second argument of `(*>)', namely `many1 digit'
In the first argument of `(<*)', namely
  `many char ' ' *> many1 digit'
```

Based on [Trivial parsec example produces a type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723208/trivial-parsec-example-produces-a-type-error) I tried adding the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` language pragma, but this hasn't helped.

I confess, I've found the learning curve to Parsec quite steep, even though I've got a bit of Haskell experience. It doesn't help that the Real World Haskell book's examples are based on Parsec 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing this code:

```
many char ' '
```

This will pass 2 arguments to the `many` function: `char` and `' '`. What you want to do is to pass the result of `char ' '` to the `many` function, which is done like this:

```
many (char ' ')
```

Comment: D'oh, I should have caught that. Actually that does solve the problem, and pushes it elsewhere. I'll ask a separate question for that.