# Cannot assign in haskell prompt

Tags: haskell

At the GHCi prompt,

I am able to do,

`Prelude Text.Parsec> :t (oneOf "aeiou")`

and get `(oneOf "aeiou") :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Char`

But when I do,

`let s = oneOf "aeiou"`

I get the following error,

```
interactive>:36:9:
    No instance for (Stream s0 m0 Char)
      arising from a use of `oneOf'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Stream s0 m0 Char)
    In the expression: oneOf "aeiou"
    In an equation for `m': m = oneOf "aeiou"
```

Could someone please tell me why I am not able to assign to s?

Comment: Maybe because of type defaulting. What about when you do `let s = (oneOf "aeiou") :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Char`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the monomorphism restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) in action.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723208/trivial-parsec-example-produces-a-type-error) is closely related, though it isn't about the `ghci` `let` but the idea is the same.